# Is it possible to debug node internal modules?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

For example, I want to add some breakpoints on the internal file `_http_server.js`,but the file does not really exist on my disk.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, at compile time the `.js` files in the source get packed into the `node` executable, which makes me unsure if/how you can set breakpoints at all on there.

What worked for me:

1. copy the relevant `.js` file from a checkout of the node source code to the current directory, e.g., [`readline.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.12.0/lib/readline.js)
2. change local imports from `require('readline')` to `require('./readline')`
3. use the undocumented [`node --expose-internals`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.12.0/src/node_options.cc#L376) flag to allow the copied `.js` file to still `require('internal/…')`
4. Use `console.log` statements / debugger on the now-local file to figure out what was happening

Comment: Didn't that require recompiling Node.js just for that one small change?

Comment: @Melab No, you copy the file that is normally compiled into nodejs into a local directory, and then you can debug it directly.

Comment: it is useful to add `const { internalBinding, primordials } = require('internal/test/binding')` to the now-local internal file

Answer (score 2):

Chrome DevTools makes this easy.

Start Node.js process with `--inspect` flag:

```
$ node --inspect
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/14be5d05-e959-47f9-bd82-e64c307d1afb
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Visit `chrome://inspect` and open up a DevTools session attached to your process:

[image: chrome://inspect page]

Search for internal files (including internal node modules like _http_server.js) and add breakpoints anywhere you'd like:

[image: Search includes internal files]

Comment: I've tried this; it doesn't work. The breakpoints never get hit.

Answer (score 0):

_http_server.js is on nodejs/lib/_http_server.js. If you want to debug this file its recommended to download the source from `github.com/nodejs/node` and start debugging. :)